# Why can't I shuffle an array properly with shuffle in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, random, shuffle

Here is a function that reproduces my  issue. I have an array. Inside the array is `array( 0 => 'l', 1 => 'j', 2 => 'b')`. Notice how `b` is always at the end no matter what I do.

```
private function fixed_shuffle($data_a, $data_b, $data_c) {
    $return_value[] = $data_a;
    $return_value[] = $data_b;
    $return_value[] = $data_c;

    for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++) {

      srand((double)microtime * 1000000);

      shuffle($return_value);

      var_dump($return_value);

      echo "<br />";

      echo implode(",",$return_value);

      echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

Demonstration of problem, notice that [2] is always 'b':

```
Current set separated by commas is 'j,l,b'.
Current answer is 'b'.
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "l" [1]=> string(1) "j" [2]=> string(1) "b" }
l,j,b
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "j" [1]=> string(1) "l" [2]=> string(1) "b" }
j,l,b
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "l" [1]=> string(1) "j" [2]=> string(1) "b" }
l,j,b
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "j" [1]=> string(1) "l" [2]=> string(1) "b" }
j,l,b
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "l" [1]=> string(1) "j" [2]=> string(1) "b" }
l,j,b
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "j" [1]=> string(1) "l" [2]=> string(1) "b" }
j,l,b
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "l" [1]=> string(1) "j" [2]=> string(1) "b" }
l,j,b
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "j" [1]=> string(1) "l" [2]=> string(1) "b" }
j,l,b
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "l" [1]=> string(1) "j" [2]=> string(1) "b" }
l,j,b
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "j" [1]=> string(1) "l" [2]=> string(1) "b" }
j,l,b
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "l" [1]=> string(1) "j" [2]=> string(1) "b" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you *do* reset `srand()` to the same value over and over, making the output of the original known, and the output of the output of the original happens to be the original, so it flips dutifully back and forth:

```
var_dump((double)microtime * 100000);
```

> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant microtime - assumed 'microtime' in Command line code on line 1
>   float(0)

```
var_dump((double)microtime(true) * 100000);
```

> float(1.3687445399327E+14

Fixing that would fix it, however, you can [just omit the `srand()`](http://www.php.net/srand):

> Note: As of PHP 4.2.0, there is no need to seed the random number generator with srand() or mt_srand() as this is now done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried your code and it seemed to work on my part except the `microtime` thing. Here is my result:

```
j, l, b
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "j" [1]=> string(1) "b" [2]=> string(1) "l" }
j, b, l
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "l" [1]=> string(1) "j" [2]=> string(1) "b" }
l, j, b
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "l" [1]=> string(1) "b" [2]=> string(1) "j" }
l, b, j
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "l" [1]=> string(1) "b" [2]=> string(1) "j" }
l, b, j
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "l" [1]=> string(1) "j" [2]=> string(1) "b" }
l, j, b
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "b" [1]=> string(1) "l" [2]=> string(1) "j" }
b, l, j
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "b" [1]=> string(1) "j" [2]=> string(1) "l" }
b, j, l
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "j" [1]=> string(1) "l" [2]=> string(1) "b" }
j, l, b
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "l" [1]=> string(1) "j" [2]=> string(1) "b" }
l, j, b
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "j" [1]=> string(1) "l" [2]=> string(1) "b" }
j, l, b
```

I just think that it was just a coincidence that `b` was always last.